# Mysql clear code in one line

Tags: mysql, sql

i was searching on google and in stackoverflow.com how can i write this code clearly and nice but found nothing.
Any idea?

MySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `allInvoice`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ocr_entity` WHERE `status` = 0) AS `new`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ocr_entity` WHERE `status` = 10) AS `notTemplate`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ocr_entity` WHERE `status` = 50) AS `withMistake`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ocr_entity` WHERE `status` = 100) AS `finished`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ocr_entity` WHERE `status` = 200) AS `skipped`  
    FROM `ocr_entity`;
```

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: too much select, and i dont know if there is another solution to write more clearly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `allInvoice`,
       SUM( `status` = 0 ) AS `new`,
       SUM( `status` = 10 ) AS `notTemplate`,
       SUM( `status` = 50 ) AS `withMistake`,
       SUM( `status` = 100 ) AS `finished`,
       SUM( `status` = 200 ) AS `skipped`  
FROM `ocr_entity`;
```

MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context, with 0 for false and 1 for true (which is why `SUM()` works).